# TableView Swift with dynamic and fixed cells

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I'm making an app that displays data from Firebase , I have a TV that has to show one fixed cell (to choose the type of data to display) and the other cell to display data from server this is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftDate

class EventiTVC: UITableViewController {

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()        
    let utente = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var Menu_button: UIBarButtonItem!

    var Eventi:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            Menu_button.target = self.revealViewController()         
            Menu_button.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))                
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Hangover_Background"))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()            
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 19)!]

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            Menu_button.target = self.revealViewController()                
            Menu_button.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 19)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]

        DeterminaInfoProprietario()
        DeterminoLocali()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        if section == 0{
            return 1
        }

        else {
            return Eventi.count
        }

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Event_Type", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Event_Type                
            return cell
        }

        else {
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Evento", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Evento
            let EventoCorrente = Eventi[indexPath.row]
            // scarico info Evento corrente                 ref.child("Eventi").child(EventoCorrente).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

                if snap.childrenCount != 0 {
                    let DatiEvento = snap.value as? NSDictionary
                    cell.Nome.text = DatiEvento?.value(forKey: "Nome") as! String!
                    cell.Locale.text = DatiEvento?.value(forKey: "Locale") as! String!

                    let urlcopertina = DatiEvento?.value(forKey: "Immagine Copertina") as! String!
                    cell.Copertina.aail_load(url: NSURL(string: urlcopertina!)!)

                    // per scaricare il colore , devo scaricare il locale
                    let locale = DatiEvento?.value(forKey: "Locale") as! String!                        
                    var Colore:UIColor? = nil             
                    var Ombra:UIColor? = nil

                    self.ref.child("Locali").child(locale!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap2) in

                        if snap2.childrenCount != 0 {
                            let DatiLocale = snap2.value as? NSDictionary                                
                            Colore = ColoriDaStringa(Colore: (DatiLocale?.value(forKey: "Colore Pagina"))! as! String)[0]
                            Ombra = ColoriDaStringa(Colore: (DatiLocale?.value(forKey: "Colore Pagina"))! as! String)[1]
                            cell.ViewC.backgroundColor = Colore!
                            cell.View_ombra.backgroundColor = Ombra!
                        }
                    })
                }

                else {
                    // Evento Cancellato? // gestire situazione
                }
            })
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            return 44                
        }else {
            return 190
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ritornaHome (Segue:UIStoryboardSegue){

    }
}
```

[image: This is what I got]

I got 2 static cell and 1 dynamic cell, it should be the other way around, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` method you should change your `if statement` from:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
```

to

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
```

Comment: Can you please accept it as an answer and maybe vote up, since it solved your problem> @GiulioSerra :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify these two functions to:

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   return Eventi.count+1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we should go with latest features. You should go with Auto layout. Auto layout has in built feature for showing dynamic height of `UITableView` `Cell`. Refer below link if you want to learn.

[Dynamic cell height UITableview](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Otherwise here we have answer of issue in your code.

In `numberOfSections()` you have set wrong condition. Just replace

```
        return 2
```

to

```
return 1
```

And

in `numberOfRowsInSection()` replace

```
if section == 0{
        return 1
    }

    else {
        return Eventi.count
    }
```

to

```
   return Eventi.count+1
```